# Docker container networking --format

Tags: docker, format, docker-network

I created a network with the name "`my_own_network`". After that, I created a container of Nginx: alpine image in this network with the name nginxApline.
Similarly, I have another container of the same image but in the network "bridge" with the name nginxAlpine2. 
I tried the below command for both containers

`docker network inspect --format '{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}' nginxAlpine`

It gave no output for nginxAlpine but it gave output(IP address of the container) for nginxAlpine2 (which was obviously excepted).
[Screenshot of output for both containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOqB7.png)

To figure out the reason on my own, I inspected containers and tried to find out that if the format is different but I found none as both were with the format.

```
NetworkSettings->Networks->**bridge**->IPAddress (for nginx2 in bridge network)
NetworkSettings->Networks->**my_own_network**->IPAddress (for nginx in created network)
```

Can someone please explain to me why this command is not working for container "nginxAlpine"?

Comment: I think your nginxAlpine container has no IP at all, run inspect without format and try to exec into the container and try to access the internet also

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with this?  (There's almost never a reason to manually look up a container's internal IP address.)  Can you include the actual commands you ran, and any relevant application source code?